# Is there a specific name for this square with two corners sharp and two corners rounded?

Tags: shapes, terminology

As a seasoned design professional I have memorised most of my shapes....triangles, circles... even rectangles, but I need to do some research on this shape, and for the life of me I cannot think "what to google"! "Square with two rounded corners" isn't working!

[image: Mystery shape]

Comment: [Square 2 rounded corners](https://www.google.es/search?rlz=1C5MACD_enFR506FR507&biw=1679&bih=1145&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=__6YW-yZK5GwkwWWkbHwAw&q=square+2+rounded+corners&oq=square+2+rounded+corners&gs_l=img.3...34144.34974.0.36076.6.6.0.0.0.0.81.435.6.6.0....0...1c.1.64.img..0.0.0....0.DezCxKdmgFg), [rectangle 2 rounded corners](https://www.google.es/search?rlz=1C5MACD_enFR506FR507&biw=1679&bih=1145&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=__6YW-yZK5GwkwWWkbHwAw&q=square+2+rounded+corners&oq=square+2+rounded+corners&gs_l=img.3...34144.34974.0.36076.6.6.0.0.0.0.81.435.6.6.0....0...1c.1.64.img..0.0.0....0.DezCxKdmgFg)

Comment: It reminds me of [a particular shape of Christmas ornament](https://goo.gl/images/NRJ3KD)

Comment: Reminds me so much of the Nokia 7600

Comment: @Mehdi - And googling "nokia 7600 shape" reveals the shape "teardrop" which I don't agree with at all! I think it's "leaf shape" like me shape I invented haha

Comment: @mayersdesign I have thought of it as a "double teardrop" of sorts, but most the time that means a tear drop within a tear drop when you search for it online

Answer (score 56, accepted):

## Leaf Shape

I found some results as *Leaf Shape* in graphic resources sites:

**[Shutterstock](https://www.google.es/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiXruHJuLXdAhWKzaQKHYz7BE0Qjhx6BAgBEAM&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.shutterstock.com%2Fes%2Fimage-vector%2Fleaf-shape-icon-362668706&psig=AOvVaw2uVLJM3bAxmv2UhWD2Dhas&ust=1536840518763846)**

[image: Shutterstock]

---

**[ALLPPT.com](https://www.free-powerpoint-templates-design.com/leaf-shape-card-banner-powerpoint-diagram-template/)**

[image]

---

**[Vexel](https://www.vexels.com/vectors/preview/72861/leaf-shaped-web-banner-templates)**
[image]

---

**[Print4mee](https://www.print4mee.com/product/leaf-shape-business-cards/)**

[image: leaf4]

---

[**PNGTREE**](https://pngtree.com/freepng/leaf-shape-information-map_3392101.html)

[image: PNGTREE]

---

**[Modes4u](https://www.modes4u.com/en/kawaii/p47841_organic-Birch-fabric-with-leaf-shape-design.html)**

[image: Fabric]

Comment: I didn't expect to like this answer as much as I did after search for a while.  I the name "leaf shape" is emergent of folksonomy, rather than coming from a more formal taxonomy — but regardless I think this is the right answer

Comment: Thanks @Danielillo I think you've cracked it. You know "leaf" did vaguely occur to me when I was writing the question, but I didn't fully think it through. Sometimes confirmation from a peer is what's needed to firm up a concept. Leaf shape it is.

Comment: @mayersdesign Leaf is good in general, but your example is an extreme version that doesn't really look like a leaf at all, so don't feel bad for not making that connection.  I might even call yours a "squared leaf shape".

Answer (score 27):

Microsoft calls it a [Round diagonal corner rectangle](https://pptcrafter.wordpress.com/page/10/). Here are the names of various rectangles (one can confirm this for oneself by mouse-hovering over these shapes in e.g. Powerpoint or Word):

[image: screengrab of various rectangles]

Answer (score 9):

Given a [squircle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squircle) is a square with rounded corners, you could call this a "half-squircle"*.

<sub>* Technically the shape you mention does not fit the mathematical definition a squircle, but it's close enough to be called that by most people in the same way that people call things that are approximately circular a circle.</sub>

Comment: If you'd ask me to draw a 'half-squircle' I'd literally cut it in half though.. Not with the opposite sides still sharp corners.

Comment: What about semi-squircle?

Comment: If you'd ask me to draw a 'half-squircle' I would assume one of us is having a stroke. 'Semi-squircle' sounds even weirder, but more accurate in this sense.

Comment: I'd like to note that a squircle is *not* the same as the typical rounded square with quarter circle corners.

Comment: Just a side-note. I would imagine that talking about the use of "squircles" during a logo presentation to a board of execs would be met with confusion and laughter. It's very esoteric so I doubt this word would be readily consumed outside of design professionals.

Comment: @J.E a semicircle is a circle cut in half (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semicircle) so it is no more accurate, it's just the proper name of a "half-circle".  I love that a `squircle` is a thing though :)

Comment: The mathematical definition of a squircle does NOT have straight/parallel edges and circular arcs like the shape discussed here, the "straight" parts of  a squircle are curved, with the curvature increasing quickly at the corners.  You can draw this leaf shape with a compass and a ruler while a squircle has constantly changing curvature.

Comment: Sounds like you took a popular water-based Pokemon and cut them in half. Mind you, I don't think it's terrible, but I somehow doubt it's standard language that any arbitrary graphics design person would get without further explanation.

Comment: @Tim Semi-squircle doesn't capture if it is half squircle half square or half squircle half circle.  Also, a semi-circle is also just a circle cut down the middle, so...

Answer (score 0):

What about a “squeaf”?

It’s fun to say.

(Square + leaf)

Comment: This sounds as if you just made it up.

Comment: I agree, it is :)

Comment: Hi Helena, while your answer is fun and original, we typically look for answers based on empirical data here (see the other answers in this Q&A for an idea). Could you [edit] your answer to include at least the reasoning behind the word 'squeaf' and why you think that's a good name for this shape? Feel free to browse around the site, add more answers and maybe ask a question of your own.

Comment: "Hey, Larry, can you make sure the text box is Squeaf shaped?" - It doesn't make much sense. While fun words are great for teams of 1, it doesn't transition well to a real development cycle. (This comment was just about adding extra rationale behind not making up words as an official answer)